# Why does Cauchy's Convergence Theorem imply the completeness of real numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Lots of textbooks on Mathematical Analysis say that:

> Cauchy's Convergence Theorem shows that, any convergent sequence
>   consisting of real numbers has a real number limit, which is called the completeness of real numbers.

In my opinion, the completeness of real numbers refers to that, if a real number sequence is convergent, it is necessarily convergent to a real number. By contrast, a rational number sequence is not necessarily convergent to a rational number,even though it converges. A classical example is that $\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n \to e(n \to \infty).$ In another word, the rational number set does not have the completeness property.

But how does the completeness of real numbers come out from Cauchy's Theorem? How to comprehend the point?

Comment: Can you explain how is your "opinion" differs from the theorem? As far as I understand the theorem also guarantee the existence of a **real** limit.

Comment: What exactly is the statement of Cauchy's Convergence Theorem? Is it that every Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ is convergent?

Comment: You have to philosophically agree that a Cauchy sequence "should" be convergent before completeness really means anything to you. Once you do that, the point is simple: you had $\mathbb{Q}$. Some Cauchy sequences in $\mathbb{Q}$ don't converge, so you add limits to all the non-convergent Cauchy sequences according to the Cauchy completion construction. You get $\mathbb{R}$. Now you have entirely new Cauchy sequences, so you have to ask: do any of them fail to converge in $\mathbb{R}$? Completeness is telling you that they don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a subtlety here regarding convergence that perhaps you have missed. When you say that

> In my opinion, the completeness of real numbers refers to that, if a real number sequence is convergent, it is necessarily convergent to a real number.

you are making a slight (but crucial) error.

Firstly, it is improper to suggest that a sequence in a space $X$ converges, but its limit lies outside $X$. Because, if a sequence is convergent then *by definition* its limit must lie in the same space.

However, there are sequences that *appear* to converge: their tails lie in intervals of smaller and smaller length, tending to zero. Such sequences are called Cauchy sequences.

Now, a Cauchy sequence in a space $X$ may or may not have a limit in the space $X$. For instance, there are Cauchy sequences in $\mathbb{Q}$, such as the one you have chosen,
$$
a_n = \left( 1 + \frac1n \right)^{n},
$$
which do not converge in $\mathbb{Q}$.

The important theorem here is that every Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ converges. This is perhaps what you meant by the Cauchy Convergence Theorem? Note the difference between the above statement and the one you have quoted in your post.

So, if you want to know why the Cauchy Convergence Theorem implies that $\mathbb{R}$ is complete, it is because completeness is defined that way: a space is said to be complete if every Cauchy sequence in $X$ is convergent. And the Cauchy Convergence Theorem says that $\mathbb{R}$ is complete.

This might be unsatisfactory, because it might appear that all we have done is make a clever definition. But I'll be happy to address any concerns if you have in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

well, if you mean by cauchy convergence theorem that any cauchy sequence converges, then yes, because this is precisely the definition of being complete and $\mathbb{R}$ often gets defined as the completion of $\mathbb{Q}$. However, your second statement is wrong, since convergence demands a limit point! hence the sequence you wrote down does not converge in $\mathbb{Q}$, but it defines a cauchy sequence there! The existence of the limit is essential! so please revise your definition of convergence.